# Determine if called from with statement

Tags: python

I would have a function that can either be called directly or via a with statement, and it should behave differently depending on how it is called, returning a context manager if called via a with statement, otherwise doing what the context manager would do directly.

e.g.

```
class Context(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        print('start')

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        print('end')
        return False


def myfunc():
    if called_from_with:
        return Context()
    else:
        print('start')
        print('end')
```

When called from a with:

```
>>> with myfunc():
>>>    print('foo')

start
foo
end
```

When called directly:

```
>>> myfunc()

start
end
```

Is there a way to do this?

Edit: My use case is for a tool I'm working on for writing html. I've put my initial code here: https://github.com/garyvdm/htmlwrite (please note it is currently a work in progress.)

I would like the user to be able to write this:

```
writer = Writer(sys.stdout)

with writer(Tag('div')):
    writer('Hello world')

writer(Tag('div', c=("Hello world 2", )))
```

Instead of this: (note the call to `.wrapped`)

```
writer = Writer(sys.stdout)

with writer.wrapped(Tag('div')):
    writer('Hello world')

writer(Tag('div', c=("Hello world 2", )))
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What if I wanted to do `context_manager = myfunc()`, then `with context_manager:`?

Comment: There is *no need* to switch behaviour. Always return a context manager, and use it correctly.

Comment: *"it should behave differently depending on how it is called"* - this sounds like a really bad idea.

Comment: If you want different behavior, make different functions.

Comment: Ok. You guys have convinced me to have 2 separate functions. If one of you want to put an answer in for such, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Context managers are not limited to `with` statements. Apart from assigning the manager to a variable before using it with `with` (`cm = writer(Tag('div'))`, then `with cm:`), you can use context manager in an [`ExitStack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack) or call the `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods separately.

The better option is to *always* return a context manager from your function. If that means that you'll also need to provide a *different* function to provide a non-contextmanager version of the behaviour, so be it.

That said, you could adapt behaviour based on the number of arguments; this is what [`TestCase.assertRaises()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#TestCase.assertRaises) does. Internally you always create a context manager, but with more arguments you simply apply he context immediately:

```
def __call__(self, tag, *args):
    # produce a context manager
    cm = WriterContext(self, tag)
    if args:
        with cm:
            for arg in args:
                self.write(arg)
    else:
        return cm
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming what you want to avoid is double context manager invocation, that is same context manager should not be doubled, I propose that you hack context manager to be reentrant.

Here's a simple example using transactions:

```
@contextmanager()
def foo(self):
    # if object can be shared across threads,
    # make sure only one thread can enter at a time
    # alternatively, inherit from threading.Local
    with self.lock:
        if self._transaction:
            yield
        else:
            try:
                with real_transaction() as self._transaction:
                    yield
            finally:
                self._transaction = None
```

Comment: Although some might say that this is not very pythonic, this still looks pretty cool, especially the `as self._transaction` part.

Comment: @Rusty: re-entrant context managers are [very pythonic](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#reentrant-cms).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I actually meant the `as` assignment part, In my (very small) experience it is only used to define new names, rather than assigning to existing ones.

Comment: @Rusty: it binds the return value of `__enter__` to a target; nothing says that that name should be *new*. :-) It essentially does the same as `target = <return value of __enter__>`; you can do the same in an `except` handler. Nothing un-pythonic about that either.

Comment: @MartijnPieters oh I see, as I mentioned before, my current experience with python is limited (2-3 months) and I've never seen that kind of usage before, so it looked like a hack to me, but it's great if it isn't, might come in handy some time.